# wxPython event from user selecting text in field?

Tags: wxpython

How do I capture the start and end points of a user's text selection in widgets such as wx.TextCtrl, wx.lib.editor, wx.richtext, and wx.stc ? What event should I bind to?

I'm just learning wxPython and have the following basic code working, based on the examples.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.editor as editor

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = editor.Editor(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'test editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you
-david

Answer (score 0):

A little late but in case it still helps. You can use the win32api module:

```
import wx
import win32api

class MyTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.hwnd = self.GetHandle()

    def _GetSel(self):
        EM_GETSEL: int = 0xB0
        n = win32api.SendMessage(self.hwnd, EM_GETSEL, 0, 0)
        return win32api.LOWORD(n), win32api.HIWORD(n)

    def IsFullTextSelected(self):
       return self._GetSel() == (0, len(self.Value))
```